# Are parentheses mandatory to include in C# methods?

Tags: c#, methods, parentheses

I have seen multiple tutorials that show C# method creation with parentheses containing parameters or simple empty. I have also seen a C# method written with out parentheses.

```
public int Value {
    get{ return _Value; }
    set{ _Value = value; }
}
```

I haven't tested out that code but **is this allowed? Is it considered bad form?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in Philip's answer, your example code is actually a Property,

But you perhaps have hit on something that many actually miss and that is that Properties are implemented using one or two methods. They get created for you by the compiler and contain the contents of each of the get and/or set blocks.

So, a property of:

```
public string Name {
  get {
    return "Fred";
  }
}
```

Is a *nicer* way of writing:

```
public string GetName() {
  return "Fred";
}
```

Answer (score 13):

That is a Property and not a method.  If you create a Method then it requires ().

Comment: Thought it does indirectly create two methods there :)

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses are mandatory when declaring or invoking a method.

As others have said, what you've shown there is a property, which is implemented as one or two methods behind the scenes (one for each of the "getter" and "setter").

However, you will *sometimes* see method names without parentheses - these are called *method groups* and are used to construct instances of *delegate types*.

For example:

```
public void Foo(string x)
{
    ...
}

...
Action<string> action = Foo;
```

Here `Action<string>` is a delegate type representing a call with a single string parameter and a void return type. This assignment creates an instance of that delegate type which will call the `Foo` method when it's invoked, e.g.

```
action("Test");
```

will call `Foo` with an argument of "Test".

Answer (score 1):

That is a property, not a method.  A method requires parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Bad form depends on context, there are a few design considerations to take into account when deciding to use a property or not.

MSDN has a nice list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx